# How to take items from an array that is in a React component's props and render to the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make my navbar dynamically show different things depending on whether the user is signed in or not using React and Redux. And actually, that has proven to be manageable, I hooked up action creators that check whether there is a user object and if there is then to switch the isSignedIn property to true and show content accordingly.

The challenge has been that I want to show that user's profile photo in the navbar too. In order to do that, my plan was to have an action creator fire off a function that will get the user's documents form the database (firebase) and return the details in state to the navbar component. Then mapStateToProps would take that content and move it into props for me to manipulate onto the users view.

I can get this all to work to a point, the component fires up and it takes a bit of time to get the users details form firebase, so theres a couple of seconds where the props.user property is empty. That's fine but then when it does return with the users content, they are stored in object in an array and I have no idea how to access them.

So this.props.user is an array with one object that has key-value pairs like userDateOfBirth: "12-12-2020" and so on. I need to access those values. I thought either this.props.user.userDateOfBirth or this.props.user[0].userDateOfBirth would work but neither does. The first just returns 'undefined' and the second returns an error "Cannot read property 'userDateOfBirth' of undefined.

Please help, this is driving me insane.

I've updated the question to include some of the code that should make this a bit more understandable. I've left the render function out of the navbar component for the sake of brevity.

The Action Creators signedIn and signedOut work as I expected. It's the currentUser Action Creator which I'm having difficulties with. I've shared as much as I think necessary, and maybe a little too much. Thanks for any help.

Code Below:

*** Navbar Component ***

```
import './NavBar.css';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import {signedIn, signedOut, currentUser} from "../actions";



componentDidMount()
{
  this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    let currentUser = user;
    if (user) {
      this.props.signedIn()
    } else this.props.signedOut();

    if (this.props.auth.isSignedIn) {
      this.props.currentUser(currentUser.uid);
    }
  });

}


 render() {

    return (
      this.props.auth.isSignedIn ?

        //If the user is signed in, show this version of the navbar

        //Overall NavBar
        <div id="navBar">
          {/*Left side of the NavBar*/}
                   <div id="navBarLeft">
                     <Link to ={"/"}
                     >
                     {/*  OLAS Logo*/}
                       <img
                         alt={"Olas Logo"}
                         id="logo"
                         src={require("../img/Olas_Logo&Brandmark_White.png")}
                       />
                     </Link>
                   </div>

            {/*Right side of the NavBar*/}
            <div id="navBarRight">

              <div id="home" className="navBarItem">
                <Link to={"/"} >
                  HOME
                </Link>
              </div>

              <div id="careerPaths" className="navBarItem">
                <Link to={"/careerPath"} >
                  CAREER PATHS
                </Link>
              </div>

              <div id="jobPostInsights" className="navBarItem">
                <Link to={"/jobPostInsights"} >
                  JOB POST INSIGHTS
                </Link>
              </div>

              <div id="careerQ&AForum" className="navBarItem">
                <Link to={"/forum"} >
                  CAREER Q&A FORUM
                </Link>
              </div>

              <div id="userProfile" className="navBarItem">
                <Link to={"/userprofile"}>
                  {this.props.user.length ? (<div>{this.props.user.user[0].userFirstName}</div>): <div>PROFILE</div>}
                </Link>
              </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        //This is a critical part of the ternary operator - DO NOT DELETE
        :

        //If the user is not signed in, show this version of the navbar

        <div id="navBar">
          {/*Left side of the NavBar*/}
          <div  id="navBarLeft">
            <Link to ={"/"}
            >
              {/*  OLAS Logo*/}
              <img
                alt={"Olas Logo"}
                id="logo"
                src={require("../img/Olas_Logo&Brandmark_White.png")}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>

          {/*Right side of the NavBar*/}
          <div id="navBarRight">
            <div/>
            <div/>


            <div id="about" className="navBarItem">
              <Link to={"about"}>
                <span className="navBarItemInner">ABOUT OLAS</span>
              </Link>
            </div>

            <div id="home" className="navBarItem">
              <Link to={"/"} >
                <span className="navBarItemInner">HOME</span>
              </Link>
            </div>

            <div id="signIn" className="navBarItem" >
              <Link to={"/signIn"} >
                <span className="navBarItemInner">SIGN IN / REGISTER</span>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


    )};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return {auth: state.auth, user: state.user}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {signedIn, signedOut, currentUser})(NavBar);
```

*** currentUser Action Creator ***

```
export const currentUser = (currentUserUid) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await getUserDocFromDB(currentUserUid);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      payload: response,
    });
  }
};
```

*** getUserDocFromDB ***

```
import getFirestoreDb from '../getFirestoreDb';

let db = getFirestoreDb();


const getUserDocFromDB = async (currentUserUid) => {

  let userDoc = [];

  await
  db.collection("users")
    .where("userFirebaseUid", "==", currentUserUid)
    .onSnapshot(
      (querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          return;
        }
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

          const {
            userDateOfBirth,
            userGender,
            userState,
            userCity,
            userTitle,
            userDescription,
            userFirstName,
            userLastName,
            userProfileImageUrl,
          } = doc.data();

          userDoc.push({
            userDateOfBirth,
            userGender,
            userState,
            userCity,
            userTitle,
            userDescription,
            userFirstName,
            userLastName,
          });
        });
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document Error: ", error);
      },
    );
  return userDoc;
};

export default getUserDocFromDB;
```

*** User Reducer ***

```
import {GET_CURRENT_USER} from "../actions/ActionTypes";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
};


export default  (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CURRENT_USER:
      return  {user: action.payload};
    default:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
  }
  };
```

*** Combine Reducers ***

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
export default combineReducers({
  user: UserReducer,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way, `this.props.user[0].userDateOfBirth` is the correct way of accessing user properties *after* the data is loaded. What is happening is the array is empty while the data is being fetched and populated in app state. Using a guard will prevent the undefined error.

Assuming the default state is an empty array:

```
this.props.user.length && this.props.user[0].userDateOfBirth
```

In react this is a pattern called [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), and would likely look more like:

```
{this.props.user.length ? (
  /* Render user component using this.props.user[0] */
) : null}
```

To make consuming the `user` object a little cleaner in components I'd convert the default state to be `null`, and have the reducer that handles the fetch response do the unpacking from the response array. Then the check is reduced to something like:

```
{this.props.user ? (
  /* Render user component using this.props.user */
) : null}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I still can't get this to work correctly. 

I'm using a ternary operator to conditionally render the navbar - v1 if the user is not signed in and v2 if the user is signed in. That works perfectly. But rendering the contents from props conditionally has proven next to impossible. I thought it was due to the data not loading quickly enough so I went back through the flow and added an extra async-await condition to the function that gets the user's doc from Firebase. Still no success. 

Any additional thoughts or solutions would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: @RoryO'Doherty Perhaps you can update your question with an actual example snippet of your code, or additionally share a running codesandox. Without seeing what your real code is doing it's nearly impossible to tell what may be going amiss.

Comment: Let me try sharing code in the question. Sorry if I'm being too vague, I'm a relatively inexperienced developer.

Comment: I've updated the question to include my code. Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: @RoryO'Doherty Can you post more of `NavBar`? Where you are trying to render `this.props.user` is where the issue lies.

Comment: Ok, no probelm.

Comment: @RoryO'Doherty Is the issue with this line: `this.props.user.length ? (<div>{this.props.user.user[0].userFirstName}</div>): <div>PROFILE</div>`? If `this.props.user` ***is*** an array, then `this.props.user.user` is likely a typo and causing trouble. If `this.props.user` is an object, then it likely doesn't have a `length` property (*it could but you'd have to have added or constructed it that way*).

Comment: That is where the issue lies. The extra user in {this.props.user.user[0].userFirstName} is confusing. I included that after adding an initial state of user: null to the User Reducer.

Which means that when I console.log(state) in the mapStateToProps function, the result is 
user: 
user: Array(1)
0: {userFirstName: "Rory", userLastName: "O'Doherty", userDateOfBirth: "15-04-1993"} 


I thought setting the Initial state of user to null would solve the issue of trying to access the array before it loaded.

It sounds like the issue is the array doesn't have a length prop?

Comment: Yeah, I think your initial `user` state should be an empty array, `const INITIAL_STATE = []` versus nesting a `user` key within, then the `length` property will always be available to check, the other option is to do the extra access in `mapStateToProps`, like `user: state.user.user`. Do you plan to add more properties to the `user` state slice? I should've asker earlier, but what is the error?

Comment: I can switch the initial state to be an empty array, and remove the extra user.  The problem is when I use a ternary operator like in this snippet, it always runs the second option. When I don't have a ternary operator and just use something like {this.props.user[0].userFirstName} then the error is "cannot read property 'userFirstName' of undefined. 

I do plan to add more properties to the user state as the user goes further and further into the product.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using private route then simply get pathname by using window.location.pathname === "user/dashboard" ? print username : "login "
Minimize tge filtration ..
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

[Drew Reese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047353/6162550) is spot on and I just wanted to add to it. You can check if the property exists, or simply render nothing if does not, as his examples show. When the state finally loads, it will **force a re-render**, the conditional will then be true, and you can then show the user profile photo or whatever other components require info from the returned api call.

This is why you might have seen a pattern of dispatching LOADING reducers, setting loading to true until the api returns and then it is set to false. You can check if loading is true in the component, and choose to render a spinner or something else instead.